# is it correct that Present participle phrase could be considered to be a sentence?

Tags: grammar, present-participles

is "Buying kitchen chairs and eating in restaurants and carrying on" a complete sentence?
I think this sentence separated by common isn't a competition for sentence. but I often see this kind of sentence in the novel.

Ove knows very well it was just an excuse because his wife wanted to get some new ones. as if that was all life was about. *Buying kitchen chairs and eating in restaurants and carrying on.**

Comment: This is basically the same issue that you asked about in [your earlier question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/310154/is-it-right-that-past-participle-adding-object-is-considered-to-a-sentence?noredirect=1#comment581493_310154), except that it uses the present participle instead of the past.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, its not a complete sentence.  It is a fragment, and these are natural enough in some contexts:

> There was only one thing Mary was afraid of. Dogs. All kinds of dogs. Big or little. Hate, loath and fear.

There is a rhetorical effect in using sentence fragments like this.  It creates an uneven and broken rhythm to the writing. A staccato effect.

Fragments are also very common in conversation.

> What's your name?
>
> James.

As usual, the context lets you fill in the missing grammar. Usually [Fragment] can be replace by "It is/was [fragment]."

In other contexts, fragments should be avoided.  I would not use fragments in a business letter.